# Encrypting a Macbook with TrueCrypt (Snow Leopard + Bootcamp)

Tags: windows, macos, truecrypt, boot-camp

I have a Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard and Windows 7 Pro (Bootcamp).

I have encrypted all the company computers with TrueCrypt and now it's the Macbook's turn. Will TrueCrypt only encrypt the Win 7 partition and will it disable Bootcamp, or would it install after Bootcamp, whereby after I select either the OS X or Windows partition under Bootcamp, the Truecrypt encryption for Win 7 would be activated?

Answer (score 0):

For Truecrypt to work, it needs a driver in the host OS. You better figure out how bootcamp works or if Truecrypt is compatible with it, so check out the Truecrypt forums.